# Enable Article Voting for unauthenticated/guest users

Tags: force.com-sites, articles

How can I enable article voting for the guest users without prompting them to login. Salesforce lets guest users vote their own article without logging in.

I want to implement similar kind of functionality. E.g. if you take this Salesforce [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_find_your_way_around.htm&type=0&language=en_US), you would be able to vote without logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Salesforce supports that

We implemented that on a project using a `lightning component` that shows the Up icon and the Down vote icon (like the standard one)

[image: UpDown]

In the apex side a controller handles the Up and Down votes to save them the Salesforce DB

Comment: Did you use the standard "Vote" object to store the results or did you create a custom object. Since we are adding the lightning component on the article details page, how can we retrieve the article ID? Is there any possibility to see the code?

Comment: you can fetch the article by implementing force:hasRecordId. in lightning side just get by component.get('v.recordId')

Comment: https://tenetizer.com/enabling-article-voting-for-guest-unauthenticated-users-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 0):

Standard vote object only supported for logged in user. For guest user, it will be only one user technically, so only one Vote can be created, so that's why custom approach is preferred using a custom object to store it.

After that, create a LWC with help of Apex controller to create an entry for each click.

1. Get the id from LWC and pass it to controller.
   `@api articleId;`// if you mark it @api, automatically recordid will have value on article detail page.
2. Create the record in custom object for each click.

`ArticleVote__c newVote = new ArticleVote__c(); newVote.ArticleId__c = articleId; newVote.VoteType__c = voteType; // Set any additional fields as needed  // Insert the new vote recordinsert newVote;`

Please go through this article to learn more here: https://tenetizer.com/enabling-article-voting-for-guest-unauthenticated-users-in-salesforce/